# Does Firefox 4 have issues with GZip?

Tags: firefox, .htaccess, gzip

Many people recommend that you use the following code in .htaccess for GZip:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Why does Firefox 4 need an exception? Or am I misunderstanding the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mozilla/4` != Firefox 4

In fact, [Firefox 4 uses `Mozilla/5`](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/09/final-user-agent-string-for-firefox-4/) as part of its [user-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent). For historical compatibility reasons ([see this](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/build/user-agent-strings.html)), most (all?) web browsers identify themselves as Mozilla (other tokens in the user agent can be used to tell Safari from Firefox from IE, etc)

Answer (score 0):

"Mozilla/4" would match things like Netscape 4 and IE 8 or earlier.  It doesn't match any modern web browser (IE9, all Gecko-based browsers, Safari, and Chrome all use "Mozilla/5" while Opera uses no "Mozilla/something" token at all).